# Installs without updating grub?

Tags: grub2, synaptic

I have a custom grub menu entry for PrimeOS that gets messed with every time I install something. Any way to do installs without automatically updating grub?

Comment: Yes, but not easily at all. It means abandoning the easy installers, dropping back 20 years and doing your own chrooting. Messy and time-consuming. It's generally MUCH easier to save your preferred GRUB config, and restore it after each install.

Comment: You haven't given details as to what OS & release you are using (esp. the OS that controls grub), nor how you added the entry (did you do it in a file that suggests you avoid because it's re-created regularly? or an intended file). Your OS & release though is the starting point.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04, grub 2.04. My work around has been a faulty grub-customizer file that fails grub update. Not elegant but leaves my custom grub.config intact and yes, I've been backing up and restoring grub file before this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding PrimeOS menu entry within grub-customizer using proper boot sequence syntax.

set root='(hd0,4)'
linux /android/kernel root=/dev/ram0 SERIAL=random logo.showlogo=1 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet DATA= USB_DATA_PARTITION=1
initrd /android/initrd.img

Now grub updates properly and doesn't break my Widows10, Ubuntu, PrimeOS triple boot tablet PC setup ;